# web server connection closes before completing the execution in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services, security

I have 3 servers. One Web server and one Application server and one Database server. 
The web server contacts the application server and the application server contacts the Database server. 
The connection is being open till the application servers actions are getting completed. 
But, there is a java script that we are trying to execute from the Application server, which in-turn have to contacts the DB server to get the desired values and display. 
Before the JavaScript part is getting executed, the connection is getting closed and we cannot pull the value from the DB. 
We need to close the server when the application completes the task. 
Any suggestion how to keep the connection to be open till the JavaScript is completed?

Comment: Where does the JavaScript run? It's a general-purpose language, but typically in ASP.Net stacks, it's only used client-side, in the browser. If you're using it elsewhere (and if it directly contacts the DB, you'd better be), you need to be clear where and how you're using it.

Comment: This question lacks a fair bit of important detail. Please use the "edit" link to add it.

Comment: If you were to run the query directly via the browser, would it return successfully? Sounds like an application error that's forcing the connection to close.

Comment: If we run the query with in the App server, we were able to run and get the result. 
But, if we run the same from Web server, the connection is lost and result is not displayed.